# WCF WebSocket Service needs to be secure TLS/SSL WSS

Tags: wcf, ssl, websocket

We have an existing WCF Web Service used for WebSockets.  We distribute our solution to our customers who host the application in IIS.  I have been tasked to make the service work with port 443 (WSS/HTTPS).  I have tried updating the Web.Config of the customBinding to use httpsTransport, but I haven't been able to connect successfully to the service using wss://.  I have uploaded a simplified sample of our application to https://github.com/kevmoens/WcfWebSocketService which uses ws://.

Here is the Web.Config updated to try to use httpsTransport

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfWebSocketService.ConnectService"
               behaviorConfiguration="WcfWebSocketService.ConnectService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webSocket"
                  contract="WcfWebSocketService.IConnectService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="webSocket">
          <byteStreamMessageEncoding />
          <httpsTransport>
            <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always"
                               createNotificationOnConnection="true"
                               />
          </httpsTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfWebSocketService.ConnectService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is a sample client that works if I change it to use WS://.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>Web Socket Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 200, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
    <input id="txtBox" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var CONNECTION;

        window.onload = function () {
            // open the connection to the Web Socket server
            CONNECTION = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:51462/ConnectService.svc');


            // When the connection is open
            CONNECTION.onopen = function () {
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('Connection opened'));
            };

            // when the connection is closed by the server
            CONNECTION.onclose = function () {
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('Connection closed'));
            };

            // Log errors
            CONNECTION.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log('An error occured');
            };

            // Log messages from the server
            CONNECTION.onmessage = function (e) {
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(e.data));
            };
        };
        
        // when we press the Send button, send the text to the server
        $('form').submit(function(){
            CONNECTION.send($('#txtBox').val());
            $('#txtBox').val('');
            return false;
        });
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to specify the SSL certificate to use when using the https protocol, but it is not configured in your configuration node. You can refer to the link below to configure the certificate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/x-509-certificate-validator

Comment: @TheobaldDu Since it is hosted in IIS and the binding on the site are set to a certificate, doesn't WCF pick up the certificate automatically?  Also does it matter that is a self signed certificate and not one from a trusted authority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the client would not work with localhost when working with IIS and Require SSL.  I was correct on the assumption that the httpTransport needed to change to httpsTransport.  Also I didn't need to add anything in the Web.Config about the certificate as it inherits the certificate from IIS.

CLIENT

Before

```
 CONNECTION = new WebSocket('wss://localhost/ConnectService.svc');
```

After

```
 CONNECTION = new WebSocket('wss://<MACHINENAME>/ConnectService.svc');
```

WEB.CONFIG

Before

```
          <httpTransport>
            <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always"
                               createNotificationOnConnection="true"
                               />
          </httpTransport>
```

After

```
          <httpsTransport>
            <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always"
                               createNotificationOnConnection="true"
                               />
          </httpsTransport>
```